# What was the motive behind "Monster sounds" of TIE fighters?

Tags: star-wars

Maybe, an engine could produce such sound, but why was it chosen (out of universe)? By no means, it looks futuristic.

Comment: Databank says that [the terrifying roar of a TIE's engines strikes fear into the hearts of all enemies of the Empire](http://www.starwars.com/databank/tie-fighter). Monsters (actually [an elephant scream + the noise of a car driving on a wet road](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TIE/LN_starfighter#Behind_the_scenes)) would sound fearsome.

Comment: In WW2, the Germans installed a wailing siren on their Stuka dive bombers to cause panic and fear. It was quite effective. They probably would have used the @Null elephant and car noises if they could have figured out how.

Comment: @MajorStackings Wow.. Good to know.

Comment: For the Stuka, see [this question over on Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9525/2556).

Comment: In-universe the sound generators were probably manufactured and sold by the same guy who convinced them that the enemies of the empire would actually hear the sound in space. :)

Comment: Then the question would be, in the Star Wars Universe, "Why does sound travel through a vacuum, unlike our Universe?"

Comment: @JasonSebring It's just another Lucas retcon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has been discussed at [some length](http://usoproject.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/ben-burtt-about-genesis-of-tie-fighter.html) by the sound's creator (Ben Burtt) in the excellent "[The Sounds of Star Wars](http://www.chroniclebooks.com/soundsofstarwars)".

> Originally, **George Lucas had seen a British documentary on PBS about
>   the Battle of Stalingrad in World War II and had noted that the firing
>   sound of some strange Nazi rockets was quite weird and interesting.
>   Lucas mentioned that it might make a great sound for the laser gun and
>   Burtt managed to find a copy of the documentary.** He then set about
>   finding sources that could emulate that sound. Luckily, at Twentieth
>   Century Fox Studios, Don Hall let Burtt go through the Fox sound
>   library, where he found recordings of some elephants that had been
>   done for an Errol Flynn movie The Roots of Heaven [1958]. In that
>   film, elephants stampeded and bellowed. with an almost shrieking sound
>   (the same sounds were used for the dinosaurs in Journey to the Center
>   of the Earth). After making a copy of that recording, Burtt realized
>   that when he slowed it down and stretched it out, he ended up with a
>   sound similar to the rocket one in the PBS documentary.
>
> **But it wasn't quite right, so Burtt took the sound of the elephant and
>   mixed it with pass-bys he'd recorded of cars during a rainstorm as
>   they sped through puddles in front of a motel where he was staying (a
>   pass-by is when a vehicle comes toward the viewer, passes by, and then
>   speeds away).**
>
> "Swoosh, the car would come by, and you heard this car plowing through
>   the water," he says. "I took that sound still thinking that I was
>   making a laser of some kind." The key "a-ha" moment occurred during
>   temp track auditions, as shots started coming in from ILM of the
>   gunport sequence.
>
> "When we did temp mixes and played it back for the crew at Park Way, I
>   would take advantage of the fresh audience, because the editors hadn't
>   heard anything with sound," Burtt explains.
>
> "The gunport sequence came along with the first trial shots of actual
>   TIEs in motion. There was pressure to just get some temporary sound in
>   for a screening, **so I grabbed a random set of sounds I liked and cut
>   in a different one each time a TIE fighter zoomed by,"** continues
>   Burtt. "One sound was the elephant shriek, the next one was a
>   slowed-down World War II warbird, the next a processed jet or rocket."
>
> After the screening was over, the only talk in the room was about that
>   elephant swoosh sound. **"That was the greatest sound for those ships
>   you could have possibly picked!"** Of course, I was saying, "Oh yeah, of
>   course". I’d really put it in because I had no other altemative, but
>   it got great reviews, so naturally it became the sound of the TIE
>   fighters."
>
> **"In World War II, the Stuka dive-bombers had an artificially created
>   siren wail created by air ducts," explains Joe Johnston, visual
>   effects art director. "They didn't serve any purpose except to create
>   this noise, which would terrify people. It was intended that the TIE
>   should achieve the same effect."**